# How can I control the size of a RecordBatch precisely?

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

While I use pyarrow to generate RecordBatch(or Table), I need to construct the data(consists of array) first. For example:

```
data = [
   ....:     pa.array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
   ....:     pa.array(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'big string xxxxxxxxx']),
   ....:     pa.array([True, None, False, True])
   ....: ]
   batch = pa.RecordBatch.from_arrays(data, ['f0', 'f1', 'f2'])
   batch.nbytes
```

The result is:

1. the size of the 'batch' is **83** bytes;
2. the number of rows in the 'batch' is 3;
3. the number of columns in the 'batch' is 4;

The question is: Can I control the size of the RecordBatch not to exceed **64** bytes？And How?
Is there some user API of pyarrow to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If can control the size not to exceed 64 bytes,  the effect should be that the RecordBatch can only be written to 3 rows instead of 4 rows.

Comment: Can the MemoryPool achieve this？